# Erro ao encontrar o arquivo: roslyn\csc.exe

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estava usando o Visual Studio 2017 normalmente em um projeto MVC quando o mesmo pediu pra atualizar alguns pacotes via nuget.

Ao fazer isso, a aplicação não quis mais compilar e apresenta o erro abaixo:

> Não foi possível localizar o arquivo 'D:\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\siteRelatorios\bpa\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.

Alguém sabe qual pacote é responsável por esse arquivo? Ou como faço pra corrigir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver, basta **NÃO** atualizar o pacote: `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` para a versão `1.0.6`

Retornei pra versão `1.0.5` e voltou ao normal.

Answer (score 8):

Eu instalei:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -Version 2.0.1
```

E o problema foi solucionado.